# Speeding up the matrix product B.T @ A @ B in python, where B is sparse and A fully dense

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, transpose, matrix-multiplication

I want to speed up the computation of the following matrix product in python: B.T @ A @ B, where

A = fully dense and symmetric matrix

B = sparse matrix

The typical dimensions of these matrices are
A = (40000, 40000), B = (40000, 2000)

What options do I have if using GPUs is not one of them?

Comment: Could you show the summary display of `B`, the one that tells us the sparse format, shape, and number of nonzero elements?

Comment: It would probably be inefficient on GPU anyway. How much sparse is the B matrix (ie. `number_of_zero/number_of_item`)? Is this operation already parallelized using your Numpy (I highly doubt it is)?

Comment: The ratio of number_of_zeros / number_of_items is ~0.99 (it's a ridiculously sparse matrix). This operation is performed  many times in my code (during a non-linear parameter estimation search, which itself is parallelized using multiprocessing), every time only the matrix B is changing (but every B matrix is equally sparse). How would I go about parallelizing this operation Using NumPy (maybe it's more efficient to parallelise NumPy and not the non-linear search).

Comment: Numpy is already parallelized really well. If your B matrix is really sparse you could make it into a sparse format and use something like the MKL library to handle the multiplication (scipy has a pretty inefficient built in dot product).

Comment: mkl_sparse_?_syprd does the exact operation you want for example